# How to solve this integral by residue theorem?

Tags: contour-integration, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I've come across this integral during a physics problem:

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dz \frac{i\Omega}{z^2-\Omega^2+i\epsilon}  e^{z} K_{-i(a+z)}(b)
\end{equation}

where $\Omega$, $a$ and $b$ are real numbers and $\epsilon\rightarrow 0^{+}$. $K$ is the Modified Bessel Function of the Second Kind.

The problem is the following: $K$ is divergent when the imaginary part of $z$ is very large so the common half-circle contour doesn't work here.

Comment: I doubt this has a closed form.

Comment: Write $K_\nu$ as an integral. Apply Fubini. You'll get a nasty cosh in the numerator. Solve complex integral. End up with a real integral, which doesn't include a Bessel function.

Comment: @vitamind Does this new integral have a closed form?